# Java Regex String

Tags: java, regex

Hi, I'm new to regular expressions and I need to extract this string:

`{"Name":"John","Tagline":"Hi","Title":"Developer","Company":"Iconnexus","Industry":"Comp","What I Do":"Android","Who do I want to meet":"Android Developers","WHOOZNEAR_PROFILEPIC":"content://media/external/images/media/4"}`

from this one:

`{"nameValues":{"Name":"John","Tagline":"Hi","Title":"Developer","Company":"Iconnexus","Industry":"Comp","What I Do":"Android","Who do I want to meet":"Android Developers","WHOOZNEAR_PROFILEPIC":"content://media/external/images/media/4"},"profileId":1,"valid":false}`

What regular expression would I use to get that string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use regular expressions, [use a JSON parser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7663467/14955).

Answer (score 0):

Or if you're really wanting to use regex to extract that part:
`^{"nameValues":(.*)$` and use the first capture group.